# Filtering and changing both arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got two arrays, for example:

```
arr1 = [3,3,2,2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1],
  [1]
];
```

I take each value from arr1 and shift values from arr2 (if it's possible).

Example:
arr1[0] = 3, arr2[0] = [1,1,1,1].
I shift three 1 from arr2; then shift arr1[0] value

Result should look like:

```
arr1 = [3,2,2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1],
  [1]
];
```

This code should work in loop so that loop stops when either there're no arr1 values or there're no arr2 values (prototype of **greedy algorithm**). I tried to use **.forEach** and **.filter** methods here but it didn't work correctly. What's the best way to do that?
I had something like:

```
arr1.forEach((arr1_value, arr1_index, arr1_arr) => {
  arr2.forEach((arr2_value, arr2_index, arr2_arr) => {
    if (arr2_value.length >= arr1_value) {
          
    }
  });
});
```

Algorithm explanation

```
arr1 = [3,3,2,2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1],
  [1]
];
```

Step 1
Shift 3 (arr1[0]=3) values from arr2[0], then shift arr1[0]

Result

```
arr1 = [3,2,2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1],
  [1]
];
```

Step 2
Shift 3 (arr1[0]=3) values from arr2[1], then shift arr1[0]

Result

```
arr1 = [2,2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1],
  [],
  [1,1],
  [1]
];
```

Step 3
Shift 2 (arr1[0]=2) values from arr2[2], then shift arr1[0]

Result

```
arr1 = [2,1,1];
arr2 = [
  [1],
  [],
  [],
  [1]
];
```

Step 4
Shift 1 (arr1[1]=1) value from arr2[3], then remove arr1[1] value

Result

```
arr1 = [2,1];
arr2 = [
  [1],
  [],
  [],
  []
];
```

Step 5
Shift 1 (arr1[1]=1) value from arr2[0], then remove arr1[1] value

Result

```
arr1 = [2];
arr2 = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
];
```

So that loop stops here 'cause there're no arr2 values left

Comment: Why is `arr2[1]` still `[1,1,1]` if 3 numbers are removed from it like the `arr2[0]` case? Why did `arr1[1]` change from `3` to `2`?

Comment: please add the final wanted result.

Comment: you expect the result of the second array as `[[1],[],[],[1]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the outer `array2` and check if the length is smaller, then continue with the next array. If not splice the array `a`, splice the item of `array1` and `break` the inner loop.

```js
let array1 = [3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    array2 = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1]],
    i = 0;
    
while (i < array1.length) {
    let count = array1[i];
    for (let a of array2) {
        if (a.length < count) continue;
        a.splice(0, count);
        array1.splice(i--, 1);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```